# Looking for a Product Guarantee registration form (Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to create a form where users can register their product guarantees on our website.

Does anyone know of a good wordpress plugin that might be able to accommodate this? This is a standalone website without WooCommerce and essentially acts as a contact form where users enter information about the products they wish to register.

The objective is for us to be able to retrieve and retain the information sent in that we can access via the wordpress dashboard.

This also needs to notify us via email when a registration has been sent in and needs to notify users of their registration via an automated email that gets sent when they click 'submit'.

I have set up a new page that I want this to sit on but is there a way to create such a form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is opinion based but I will try and suggest you use one of the many form management plugins.

Just search for forms in plugins.
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/search/forms/

Contact-form 7, Ninja Forms and Gravity Forms come to mind and should be able to do what you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with these two:

- [Contact Form 7](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)
- [Gravity Forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For the record.   [ER Forms](https://www.easyregistrationforms.com) seems to do the trick. I do have a separate query however as I want the end user to be able to click a button to add more text fields to the form so they can register as many products as they wish but i'll flag this up in a separate question